# iOS Swift how to incrementally draw to a UIImage?

Tags: uiimage, swift4, drawing, core-graphics, ios12

**How can I use iOS core graphics to incrementally draw a large data set in a single image?**

I have code which is ready to process the entire dataset at once (over 100,000 rectangles) and produces a single image. This is a very long running operation and I want this dataset to be incrementally drawn 1000 rectangles at a time, displaying these small image updates (like images downloaded from internet in the 90s)

My questions are: Would I keep the reference to the same `context` throughout the operation and simply add elements to it? - OR - Should I be capturing the current image using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` , then drawing it in a new context and drawing additional rectangles on top of it?

Bonus question - is this the right approach if I want to use multiple threads to append to the same image?

```
   let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    context.setStrokeColor(borderColor)
    context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(borderWidth))
    for elementIndex in 0 ..< data.count {

        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        let marker = CGRect(x: toX(elementIndex),
                            y: toY(elementIndex),
                            width: rectWidth,
                            height: rectHeight)

        context.addRect(marker)
        context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    }
    // Save the context as a new UIImage
    let myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if let cgImage = myImage?.cgImage,
        let orientation = myImage?.imageOrientation {

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 2, orientation: orientation)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- Dispatch the whole thing to some background queue;
- periodically call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` and dispatch the image view update to the main queue

E.g., this will update the image view every ¼ second:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    var lastDrawn = CACurrentMediaTime()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

    for _ in 0 ..< 100_000 {
        // draw whatever you want

        let now = CACurrentMediaTime()
        if now - lastDrawn > 0.25 {
            self.updateImageView()
            lastDrawn = now
        }
    }

    self.updateImageView()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Where:

```
func updateImageView() {
    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Thus:

```
func buildImage(of size: CGSize) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        var lastDrawn = CACurrentMediaTime()

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

        for _ in 0 ..< 100_000 {
            self.someColor().setFill()
            UIBezierPath(rect: self.someRectangle(in: size)).fill()

            let now = CACurrentMediaTime()
            if now - lastDrawn > 0.25 {
                self.updateImageView()
                lastDrawn = now
            }
        }

        self.updateImageView()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}

func updateImageView() {
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}

func someRectangle(in size: CGSize) -> CGRect {
    let x = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size.width)
    let y = CGFloat.random(in: 0...size.height)
    let width = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(size.width - x))
    let height = CGFloat.random(in: 0...(size.height - y))

    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
}

func someColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                   green: .random(in: 0...1),
                   blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                   alpha: 1)
}
```

Yields:

[image]

Now, I’m not calling CoreGraphics directly, but you can and it will work the same.